# Отследить изменение URL-адреса страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

Есть сайт на котором обновление страницы и переход по ссылкам реализован AJAX-ом, доступа к редактированию сайта нет, поэтому пишу расширение для Chrome которое будет реализовывать редактирование HTML кода для моих целей.
Проблема в том, что при переходе между страницами сайта jQuery отваливается и не переопределяется на элементы, так как не происходит перезагрузка страницы.
Как отследить изменение URL и повторно запустить jQuery при переходе?

P.S: ссылки на сайте представлены не хешем, а обычным URL:

```
https://url.com/url/url
```

Comment: Что значит «jquery отваливается»? Если вы имеете в виду, что перестаёт работать подписка на события вида `$('селектор').on('событие', функция)`, то вместо этого просто напишите `$(document).on('событие', 'селектор', функция)` и всё станет нормально

Comment: @andreymal помимо подписки на события необходимо добавить пару блоков div на страницу, и их таким способом уже не реализуешь. Или реализуешь?) Блоки одни и те же, добавляться они должны на каждую из страниц после определенного элемента.

Comment: @Евгений таки да, не реализуешь. Однако я бы рекомендовал в первую очередь покопаться в скриптах самого сайта — весьма вероятно, что там найдётся какое-нибудь «легальное» событие изменения URL аккурат после обновления контента ajax-ом)